# Using jQuery how can i on hover make an element active and make the rest of its siblings change sizes? without DIV dropping to the next line?

Tags: jquery, html, css, hide, show

I am trying to create an hide and show content 4 boxes in an container next to each other as one opens (active) and grows in width displaying content the rest should slightly move in width with out the last div being pushed down a line > Here is my script:

```
$('.box').hover(function(){        
    //DO SOMETHING
    $(this).addClass('active');
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).children('.show').show("fold", 1000);
    }

    }, function() {
          $(this).children('.show').hide("fold", 1000);
          //DO SOMETHING
          $(this).removeClass('active');        
     });
```

this is my html :

```
    <div id="lb1" class="box">
        <div class="show" style="display:none">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lb2" class="box">
    <div class="show" style="display:none">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lb3" class="box">
    <div class="show" style="display:none">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lb4" class="box">
    <div class="show" style="display:none">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any one have any ideas here is also my eexample on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hanieelr/d3g40xpa/

Comment: Post your HTML code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.box').hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).children('.show').show("fold", 1000);

    $(this).siblings().addClass("smaller");    //make siblings smaller

}, function () {
    $(this).children('.show').hide("fold", 1000);

    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("smaller"); //resotre siblings width
});
```

and css:

```
.smaller {
    width: 23.33333333%;  /* (70/3)% */
}
```

Check it out: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d3g40xpa/3/)

Comment: Thank you !! it looks like that will work .... i was almost there just wrote it wrong !  Thanks Again